# SXA what is the purpose of the Media folder under a Site

Tags: sxa, media-library

What is the purpose of the Media folder under a site in SXA?
Technically this seems to behave the same way as the regular media library, but I'm just not sure why you would use this, or if there are any implications of using this vs the regular media library?

[image]

One possible advantage I can think of is to simplify publishing just one site in a multi-tennant solution, because you could select your site's root node and publish from there and not have to either do a site-wide publish, or individually publish the site node and then the corresponding media library folder.

Comment: Or possibly to make management of security across tenants simpler, by not spreading it across multiple locations (e.g. content + media library)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Media Library scope for site

Every dialog where you have to select media item will be scoped to **Media** (Virtual Media Folder)

So first and very important role is to scope which part of Media Library is available for editors on the current site (you will set this up using **Additional Children** field), see image below

[image]

[image]

### Easy upload/quick access

In fact, this is the same Media Library as the regular one. This node presents only scoped view. See path and available buttons on the ribbon.

[image]

Authors can easily manage media directly from Site,  without the need of searching proper folder, nested somewhere in Media Library.