# Media datasource using Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, media-library, datasource

How do I add media datasource (I want customers to able to select images from a particular folder) in Sitecore SXA using experience editor. Currently,I have added datasource in the template and works fine for content editor but shows all images when I try changing it through experience editor.

Comment: You might find an answer to your question here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/sxa-what-is-the-purpose-of-the-media-folder-under-a-site

**Sitecore docs:** https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/configure-the-scope-of-the-media-library-for-an-sxa-site.html

Comment: Check Dawid answer here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/17099/237