# Set a particular path as datasource location for image field in SXA instead of entire media folder

Tags: sxa

For an image field in a template, I set a particular folder location as a source. I want to redirect the user to that folder to select the image and hide other media items. When browsing the image through content editor it redirects the user to the specific folder location, but when browsing the image from experience editor it redirects the user to Media(virtual folder) folder available under tenant site and lists all the images. Is there any way to redirect the user to a particular path under Media folder when browsing the image in experience editor?

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the code it is not possible at the moment. You have two options:

- override `ChooseImage` command from Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing
- contact Sitecore Support and register this a bug - I consider this as a bug, we should handle such situations in SXA. The fix should be straining forward as far as I can see in code.